# Reading in nested blob using python returns HTTP 400 error

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using Python to read in blobs using list blob and generate_blob_shared_access_signature but receive an HTTP 400 error when i attempt to read in a blob that is in a nested file (ex. it works fine with folder/file but not folder/folder/file)

```py
blobList = blob_service.list_blobs(<container name>)

for blob in blobList:  

    sas_token = blob_service.generate_blob_shared_access_signature(<container 
    name>,blob.name, permission=BlobPermissions.READ, expiry=datetime.utcnow() + 
    timedelta(hours=1))

    blob_url_with_sas = blob_service.make_blob_url(<container name>, blob.name, 
    sas_token=sas_token)

    # pass the blob url with sas to read in excel to data frame
    df = pd.read_excel(blob_url_with_sas)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code.

Comment: Can you include the error?

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code a bit as below and make it run on my Azure Storage account, then I found it works fine.

```
from azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice import BaseBlobService
from azure.storage.blob import BlobPermissions
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

account_name = '<my storage account>'
account_key = '<my storage account key>'
container_name = 'test'

blob_service = BaseBlobService(
    account_name=account_name,
    account_key=account_key
)

blobs = blob_service.list_blobs(container_name)
import pandas as pd
for blob in blobs:
    if blob.name.endswith('xlsx'): # I added it to check for my blob whether be excel file
        print(container_name, blob.name)
        sas_token = blob_service.generate_blob_shared_access_signature(container_name,blob.name, permission=BlobPermissions.READ, expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1))
        blob_url_with_sas = blob_service.make_blob_url(container_name, blob.name, sas_token=sas_token)
        df = pd.read_excel(blob_url_with_sas)
        print(df)
```

The result as below.

```
test myfolder/excel/testing.xlsx
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
test excel/testing.xlsx
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

So I doubt your issue was caused by other reason, not by the nested file.

Meanwhile, I suggest you can consider to directly use [`list_blob_names`](https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/ref/azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.html#azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.BaseBlobService.list_blob_names) function instead of `list_blobs` to get the list of blob names.

```
blob_names = blob_service.list_blob_names(container_name)
import pandas as pd
for blob_name in blob_names:
    if blob_name.endswith('xlsx'): # I added it to check for my blob whether be excel file
        print(container_name, blob_name)
        sas_token = blob_service.generate_blob_shared_access_signature(container_name,blob_name, permission=BlobPermissions.READ, expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1))
        blob_url_with_sas = blob_service.make_blob_url(container_name, blob_name, sas_token=sas_token)
        df = pd.read_excel(blob_url_with_sas)
        print(df)
```